# It is possible to bind collection of different viewmodels in some viewcollection (c# XAML WPF)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, catel

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Views:Message110FirstView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Messages
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>>(MessagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessagesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData MessagesProperty = RegisterProperty("Messages", typeof(ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>), null);
```

My question relates to this part of xaml:

```
<Views:Message110FirstView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
```

So, how to make different views in this place.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Please try add more details to your question and preferably code as well if possible.

Comment: this is a hell of a malformed question. no code, no calrity on what is pretended....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you want change view based in viewmodel.

It is appropriate to use `DataTemplates` if you want to dynamically switch `Views` depending on the `ViewModel`:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
   <Window.Resources>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Window>
```

If `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelA`, then `ViewA` will be displayed and `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelB`, then `ViewB` will be displayed.

The best example I've ever seen and read it is made by [Rachel Lim. See the example.](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you! It works like expected!!

Comment: @David I am really glad that I've helped to you!:)